# Class defined without specifying a base class. Cannot find interface declaration for UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have a created a new project and added a new class called `MyViewController`. My code compiles fine when `MyViewController` is a subclass of `NSObject` but when I change it to inherit from `UIViewController` I get these two error messages:

```
Class "MyViewController" defined without specifying a base class
```

and

```
Cannot find interface declaration for "UIViewController", superclass of "MyViewController".
```

What is wrong with my header file?

### MyViewController.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface LBAHypnosisViewController : UIViewController

@end
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Foundation doesn't include `UIViewController`, which is part of UIKit. Add this to your header file.

`#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>`

You may notice that many projects include both Foundation and UIKit in their prefix header. This automatically includes them in every file. Older versions of Xcode would do this for you when creating a new project.

Comment: +1 Definitely put it in the precompiled header file (the .pch one).

Comment: Using modules is the preferred solution nowadays.